# Casting JSONArray to Iterable<JSONObject> - Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, json-simple

I am using [Json-Simple](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/package-summary.html) in Kotlin.

In what situations could this cast:

```
val jsonObjectIterable = jsonArray as Iterable<JSONObject>
```

Become dangerous? `jsonArray` is a `JSONArray` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it successfully, since [JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) **is-A** `Iterable`.  but it can't make sure each element in [JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) is a [JSONObject](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html).

The  [JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html)  is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `List`, which means it can adding anything, for example:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray()
jsonArray.add("string")
jsonArray.add(JSONArray())
```

When the code operates on a downcasted generic type `Iterable<JSONObject>` from  a raw type `JSONArray`, it maybe be thrown a `ClassCastException`, for example:

```
val jsonObjectIterable = jsonArray as Iterable<JSONObject>

//    v--- throw ClassCastException, when try to cast a `String` to a `JSONObject`
val first = jsonObjectIterable.iterator().next()
```

So this is why become dangerous. On the other hand, If you only want to add [JSONObjec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)s into the [JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html), you can cast a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) [JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html) to a generic type `MutableList<JSONObject>`, for example:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val jsonArray = JSONArray() as MutableList<JSONObject>

//      v--- the jsonArray only can add a JSONObject now
jsonArray.add(JSONObject(mapOf("foo" to "bar")))

//      v--- there is no need down-casting here, since it is a Iterable<JSONObject>
val jsonObjectIterable:Iterable<JSONObject> = jsonArray 

val first = jsonObjectIterable.iterator().next()

println(first["foo"])
//           ^--- return "bar"
```

Comment: I see. This jsonArray is the response of an API I trust (and is supposed to return a JSONArray of underlying JSONObjects). Therefore I could consider this as completely safe, right?

Comment: @pk1914 No. the json data type is not only have `JSONObject`&`JSONArray` , but also have `string`,`boolean`,`number`. and a `JSONArray` also can add any type of `Object`, e.g: add another json array `add(JSONArray())`.

Answer (score 1):

Following is rather a simple implementation.

Suppose Your Object is **Person**

```
data class Person( val ID: Int, val name: String): Serializable
val gson = Gson()
val persons: Array<Person> = gson.fromJson(responseSTRING, Array<Person>::class.java)
```

Now persons is an **Array** of **Person**